# Architectural considerations for having a portable C++ domain layer interfaced with Java(JNI) and C#(C++/CLI)

Tags: c#, java, .net, c++-cli, java-native-interface

I need to make a desktop app which is pretty complex and handles a particular
domain. The domain has entities at the back end. I want the UI of this desktop app to be portable
to different frameworks such as Java(Eclipse RCP Plugin) and .NET(Visual Studio Plugin). So

1.)can I write the domain layer using C++ and interface with Java using JNI for Java
2.)use same C++ layer as point 1.) for interfacing with .NET (C++/CLI) as plugin for VStudio

What are the architectural considerations, pitfalls, future issues one will face if one
relies on a portable C++ layer interfaced with higher level APIs like Java and C# for a rich
client desktop application

For example one of the issue I will face is that I cannot debug and step into Native code from Java.
Are there many such items?

Should I just rewrite my domain layer using .NET and Java  for each type of environment rather than keeping it portable as C++ layer?

Why isn't such an approach adopted by the industry?
What are the practical issues one faces when one has a JNI layer in between the View and Domain Layer?

Comment: Personally I would use the most productive layer as much as possible.  Is there a reason you have to use C++?

Comment: I have this desktop app already in wxwidgets which is C++, and the domain layer is already been designed in C++, i want to resue the same domain layer and port it as plugins to Eclipse and Visual Studio

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Interfacing with domain models in another language / on another platform is **really painful** and my main architectural advice would be to avoid going there.

If you want a portable desktop app, I think you are better off **writing it end-to-end in Java** (or perhaps another JVM language like Scala or Clojure if you are one of the people who thinks that Java itself is a bit old-fashioned).

Rationale:

- You'll **only need to write the GUI layer once** as Java will give you access to all the environments you need. You can run Java desktop apps pretty much everywhere that has a JVM, without recompiling. You just need to take a little care to avoid hard-coding platform specific features (e.g obvious stuff like don't assume "\" as a file separator, you need to use the portable `File/pathSeparator` instead).
- This **avoids the complexities** of having to do a lot of cross-language interfacing. This is inherently a hard problem, since the languages have different object format and method calling semantics.
- Java has a great **open source library ecosystem** with respect to portable code.
- You can make pretty decent **portable UIs** in Java for most purposes (using Swing or SWT), and this is probably better in the long run than developing a custom UI layer for each target platform.
- If you are smart, you can architect the app so that the GUI interacts with the back end domain objects through a **clean and simple API**. If you do this, then it will be easier to add new GUI options in the future (for example a web-based front end).

Writing the app end-to-end in .Net is also clearly feasible and might even be a bit easier on the GUI side given how good Microsoft's GUI-building tools are, but has the big disadvantage that you're now effectively locked into Windows, so your portability and platform flexibility goes out of the window. In addition (though this will depend on your domain) I think the Java ecosystem has the overall edge in terms of library ecosystem and tool support (with things like Maven).

Answer (score 0):

When you want a cross language data model, a common pattern is to use a DSL to describe the domain model and generate the code from that. e.g. proto buffers.  That way you can have native C++, Java, C# etc code for a common domain model.

---

One of the pitfalls of using a C++ library from Java is it doesn't feel like a Java library.  You have to do all sorts of unnatural things to use it and you end up adding a layer to make it more Java friendly.  I imagine its the same for C#

> For example one of the issue I will face is that I cannot debug and step into Native code from Java. Are there many such items?

Netbeans supports Java + Native code debugging and you can step into native code from Java and debug both.

> Should I just rewrite my domain layer using .NET and Java for each type of environment rather than keeping it portable as C++ layer?

I would have said yes, but that is me.  For you it could make sense to leave in C++.  There are pluses and minuses both ways.

> Why isn't such an approach adopted by the industry?

Developing in Java and C# (and other virtual machine languages) is often seen as more productive and easier to find people who can support it.

> What are the practical issues one faces when one has a JNI layer in between the View and Domain Layer?

You have to mirror the domain model, as you cannot just import it. i.e. all the data model you expose needs to be translated. This requires creating Java versions of the exposed model and well as translation code. (Another good reason to have all of it generated)

Comment: Can a DSL be used and is it actually used in the industry for writing massive rich client desktop apps which are scalable and extendable?

Comment: Most complex data models have a DSL AFAIK.  Often they are loaded into the domain model itself for reflective/documentation purposes.  The DSL can also be used to generate the documentation and even charts and diagrams. This ensures that one central change is reflected across many pieces which need to be the same. UML is a common choice because of the tools support but I find it bloated. ;) Its worth have a look at in any case.